# How to forward replies using RMM and Triggered Send?

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, triggered-send

Currently we use RMM without issue and we route email replies to the assignee using the Sender Profile, which works great. We would like to add an additional step of *also* forwarding the reply to a repository mailbox. It looks as if this can be done using the "Forward using Triggered Send" option in the Sender Profile, however it is unclear how to specifically accomplish it. The settings of a Triggered Send do not make any sense in this context (forwarding an email internally, not sending one externally). I found a different topic similar to this ([Can I forward RMM replies to multiple email addresses?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/165614/can-i-forward-rmm-replies-to-multiple-email-addresses)) but the Triggered Send option wasn't mentioned so I wanted to explore this possibility. Has anyone tried this or found a solution for something like this?

Answer (score 5):

This is a great question. You're on the right track. I would use the 'Forward using Triggered Send' option.

However, in order to forward the reply to another address, you will first need to open a support ticket to enable the CC and BCC feature on your account. Once you do, you will note that they appear as an option when creating a Triggered Send:

[image: Send Options]

Now, back to answer your question. You first need to create a simple email that you will use for your Triggered Send. As you want to forward the email reply, you can simply use RMM Personalization Strings.

Just create a new Paste HTML email with the subject line `%%_RMM_ReplySubject%%` and `%%_RMM_ReplyBodyHTML%%` in the body, nothing else is required (unless your account requires you to include the physical mailing address and profile center, in which case add those to your email from the Snippets menu).

[image: email]

Here are the steps:

1. Create Paste HTML email (as per above screenshot)
2. Create Triggered Send, selecting the email that you created in previous step and adding the required CC/BCC addresses
3. Start the Triggered Send
4. Create a new sender profile selecting the triggered send you created earlier (see screenshot below)

[image: Triggered Send]

Then when you send the email using that Sender Profile, and the Subscriber replies to the email, the email reply (including the original email message) will be sent to the email address you configured in the Sender Profile and also to the CC/BCC address configured in the Triggered Send.

Comment: Thank you Eliot for providing a great solution. Somehow when I include %%_RMM_ReplySubject%% to the subject line of my email, as per your example, it does duplicate the subject line in the received replied to messages. Removing the %%_RMM_ReplySubject%% from the email subject line does the trick and send replies to multiple email address with only one single subject line as expected.

Comment: For some reason I can't get this to work, followed your exact steps. The forwarding works when I don't check the "Forward using triggered send" checkbox. Are there any special requirement to the triggered send? I just created a triggered DE with the standard Email and SubscriberKey fields, are any other fields necessary to make this work? Or perhaps a particular Sender Profile needs to be selected for the triggered send? Appreciate any help.

Comment: Nevermind, found I made a mistake in the triggered send DE. Added a field that can't be null.